Buy pumpfun error
When I use https://docs.pumpapi.fun/trade_transaction_api this docs generate pumpfun transaction
And I sign and send the transaction
this is my transaction data.
const data = {
      trade_type: 'buy',
      mint: '4C1JUVirUnu15whkxqJNG55rNiFufqWRviigeLgxpump',
      amount: 0.023008029,
      slippage: 2,
      priorityFee: 0.00003, // Optional
      userPublicKey: '......',
    };

And it is error.

AnchorError thrown in programs/pump/src/lib.rs:136. Error Code:
TooMuchSolRequired. Error Number: 6002. Error Message: slippage: Too
much SOL required to buy the given amount of tokens.

Who can tell me why
